# Node.JS bind Events to Variables?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible in node to bind events to variables? Eg having an array and trigger an callback function if the array length falls bellow 10.

Comment: [With `Object.observe()`, eventually, yes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe). An early implementation is [available with `node --harmony`](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es7/#Object.observe), but may see changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running Node >= 0.11.13 you can use the ES6 feature Object.observe.

```
var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

Array.observe(nums,function(changes) {  
  if(nums.length < 10) {
    console.log('Array nums has less than 10 elements!');
  }
});

var popped = nums.pop();
```

If running the unstable branch is not your thing you can use one of the many polyfills / shims:

[npmjs.org](https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=observe))

Comment: Do you mean `Object.observe`?

Comment: Array.observe provides more info about the nature of the change to the array.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/observe